# Magento 2 - load cms page

Tags: magento2, controllers

I am attempting to load a CMS Page from my controller.  The community here was kind enough to help me with a CMS Static Block - and now I need a pointer in the right direction for a cms Page.

What is the proper syntax to load a CMS Page by identifier or block id and what factory supports this type of loading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution.  Documenting for posterity.

```
...
use Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory;

protected $pageFactory;

public function __construct(...,PageFactory $pageFactory,...) {
...
$this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
...
}

public function loadCMSPage() {
...
$page = $this->pageFactory->create()->load(<PAGE URL OR ID HERE>);
...
}
```

Comment: Please change $pagefactory to $pageFactory in construct argument, it will not work in Linux server.

Comment: @Kevin Hill  Awesome. How can I page information per store view I've tried `$this->_pageFactory->create()->setStoreId(1)->load(51)` but it doesn't work?

Comment: @Juliano Vargas Have you find the solution to load cms page by store id? I am also looking for the same thing.Kindly share your experience

Comment: @aravind I haven't worked on it yet. But I have something that I would like to try: Which is create a link between the cms pages E.G : I have 3 store view therefore I need to create 3 `help.html` page one for each store then add new field in the admin cms form to display all the cms pages from the main store that way I can then select help.html in store 2 and 3 so they are linked when I hit the url:`../help.html` I get id fetch new column that has `link_id` and load all cms data by that column if that make sense it's just a theory but idea is to link pages with one another.

Comment: @Juliano Vargas thanks for your idea.But i have managed to solve the issue by adding filter to a function  which  extends searchbuilder. It gets me only the stores where the cms page is active

Answer (score 2):

There is a special model for this: [GetPageByIdentifierInterface](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Cms/Api/GetPageByIdentifierInterface.php) 
It is available since 2.3

Comment: really good find, thanks!